# Using a variable in GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to use a single value variable defined in a stored procedure in a GROUP BY query as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE test_table
(
    id uuid NOT NULL,
    no int4 NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE bigger_table
(
    id uuid NOT NULL,
    no int4 NOT NULL,
    count int4 NOT NULL,
    time timestamp NOT NULL
);

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test()
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$$
DECLARE
    v_now timestamp;
BEGIN
    v_now = now();
    INSERT INTO bigger_table (no, count, time)
    SELECT no, COUNT(*), v_now FROM test_table
    GROUP BY no;
END
$$;
```

Here, **v_now** is effectively a constant and I know it, but Postgres doesn't so it wants it be either included in GROUP BY clause or in an aggregation function. How can I convince it to use the variable here?

Comment: put a max() around it in the select statement

Comment: @VvdL But what if the type of variable was something unsortable, such as a UUID? Also how would the performance be affected for lots of rows

Comment: If it's a constant, then why include it in the SELECT to begin with? Also what are you doing with the result of that select? As written, this procedure will result in an error ("Query has no destination for result data") anyway. And why use a variable, not just `now()` directly in the SELECT?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I need to insert the result of group by to another table, but that table has extra columns that need to be filled with variables. (edited the question to make it more clear)

Comment: `SELECT no, COUNT(*), now() FROM test_table GROUP BY no;` works just fine

Comment: For not using now() directly, this code executes in a for loop and all the iterations need to have the same timestamp.

Comment: If it is constant, why would it hurt to add it to the `GROUP BY`?

Comment: [As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT)  `now()` is an alias for `transaction_timestamp()` so the value will not change throughout the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to put an alias on v_now and use this alias on group by?

```
CREATE TABLE test_table
(
    id uuid NOT NULL,
    no int4 NOT NULL
);

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test()
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$$
DECLARE
    v_now timestamp;
BEGIN
    v_now = now();
    SELECT no, COUNT(*), now() v_now FROM test_table
    GROUP BY no, v_now;
END
$$;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yech. People love constraint. But...
You cannot  `INSERT INTO bigger_table (no, count, time)` because You already defined `id uuid NOT NULL` !

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test()
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$$
DECLARE
    v_now timestamp;
BEGIN
    v_now := now();
    INSERT INTO bigger_table (id,no, count, time)
    SELECT gen_random_uuid(),
           no,
           COUNT(*) over(partition by no ),
           v_now FROM test_table;
END
$$;
```

- Don't use timestamp: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_timestamp_.28without_time_zone.29
- `now()` return timestamp with time zone !
  `select pg_typeof(now());` return `timestamp with time zone`

Comment: Or just set a default on id, eg.
`id uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT gen_random_uuid()`

Comment: Yes. @MilesElam You are right!